# Как сделать редирект на заблокированном сайте?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Как возможно обойти блокировку сайта провайдером? Должны же быть какие-то  варианты?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы являетесь пользователем сайта, то можно воспользоваться Tor-ом, VPN-ом и так далее. Если вы является владельцем сайта, то можно либо разбираться с теми, кто заблокировал, либо заняться зеркалированием сайта.

Comment: А при чём тут `.htaccess`?

Comment: Я владелец сайта. Сделал ещё несколько копий сайта на разных доменах. Вот и не знаю что делать с заблокированным сайтом, трафик с поиска как-то нужно перевести на другой сайт. А яндекс роботу он тоже будет заблокирован? Хотя бы временно, пока страницы в поиске остались.

Comment: Или имеете в виду в яндексе добавить зеркала к сайту?

Comment: Зависит от того, каким провайдером пользуется робот Яндекса. Это лучше уточнять в Яндексе. Так как запросы блокируются и не доходят до вашего сервера, то никакие правила в .htaccess не помогут обойти блокировку.

Comment: А в Яндекс.Метрика (или где-то ещё) можно добавлять зеркала? Если можно, то стоит добавить.

Comment: В яндекс вебмастер я что-то видел подобное

Comment: А там наверное с www и без только

Comment: В справке Яндекса всё же стоит поискать как перенести сайт на новый домен без выпадения из выдачи поиска. Пользователям о смене домена (а точнее список зеркал) можно сообщить, например, при помощи email-рассылки.

Comment: Постоянных пользователей нет, товар можно сказать одноразовый.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов:

1. [Vpn](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPN) (англ. Virtual Private Network — виртуальная частная сеть) — обобщённое название технологий, позволяющих обеспечить одно или несколько сетевых соединений (логическую сеть) поверх другой сети (например, Интернет).

Ты например покупаешь сервер у зарубежного провайдера, или провайдера который не блокирует доступ к твоему сайту, устанавливаешь на него сервер vpn --> далее на своём Пк подключаешься к зарубежному серверу. И через него выходишь в интернет. Таким образом ты попадаешь в сеть из сети зарубежного провайдера у которого доступ к ресурсу не заблокирован.

2. [Proxy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)

Есть платные и бесплатные сайты, которые позволяют обращаться к сайтам, через свои сервера. Т.е. они принимают запрос от тебя направляют его от своего имени на  заблокированный сервер и тебе возвращают ответ. Таким образом ты общаешься с сайтом например, через сервер посредника.

Есть ещё техгологии [tor](https://www.torproject.org/) и [i2p](https://geti2p.net/ru/) - которые также позволяют "скрыть" свои сетевые запросы от своего провайдера.

Comment: Пользователей же не заставишь прокси пользоваться.